# Extracting two numbers from a string using java

Tags: java, regex, string

> "Tracking info Latitude: 3.9574667 Longitude: 7.44882167"

The structure of the message string will not change only the figure will be changing.

Comment: Is regex a requirement?

Comment: @TheWanderer No any method will be appreciated

Comment: put in some effort before asking. You can pretty easily find an answer on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you don't even need regex. Just split the String and call the right indices:

```
String latLongString = "Tracking info Latitude: 3.9574667 Longitude: 7.44882167"; //yours obviously won't be hardcoded
String[] split = latLongString.split(" ");
String lat = split[3];
String lon = split[5];
```